# Samba share on external drive delays SSH logins

Tags: mount, ssh, samba, nas

I have a Ubuntu Server 18.04 as well as a NAS on my network. The drives on the NAS are configured to stop spinning after a bit of idle time; they take a noticeable time to start up when needed. That is fine, though.

When I login to the server over SSH, I notice the powered-down drives on the NAS  are started up, and only when they are running at full speed am I connected to the server.

Question: how can I avoid the NAS being started up when I login?

Why would the SSH service need the drive to let me login, anyway? Subsequent logins are instantaneous, as long as the NAS is still spinning.

The NAS is mounted on the server as two `cifs` shares on `/mnt/tower` and `/mnt/tower2`. The shares are  accessible to my user account. However, I don't need to login to the server in order to access the NAS, I can do that straightaway. (This makes the delay all the more annoying.)

Comment: Where are the NAS CIFS shares mounted ? Do the user need access to one or the other CIFS share to complete login ?

Comment: The mount points are both in `/mnt`. There are no obvious references to `/mnt` in any of the startup files, as far as I can see.